# HTML5 datetime-local input field vs jQueryui datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

So I just found out that you can get the datetime picker functionality that jQuery libraries offer by just using an input field with type datetime-local.

I haven't seen much info about it on the net. Are there reasons not to use it? Is it supported across all browsers?

Comment: The ui is different across browsers and can change with any updaate, not all browsers support it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Musa said, the UI for `input[type=date]` is different across operating systems and even browsers (some modern browsers don't even support it). Hopefully the input type will be more widely supported, however there will likely not be support for older browsers/versions.

If you want to use the cool `input[type=date]` syntax, don't fret! There are Javascript polyfills that provide this functionality for you when the browser doesn't!

As [HTML5Please suggests](http://html5please.com/#type=date), use `input[type=date]` with caution and make sure you have a polyfill such as [Webshims](https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/cfgs/input-datetime-local.html) or [HTML5Widgets](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/creating-cross-browser-html5-forms-now-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets-2/).